# how can i solve GoogleApiManager SERVICE_INVALID for App with Location permission?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-location

i'm new to coding and as a final project on a course I decided to build and Android app, since it's what I want to focus my studies later (kinda regret it now...).

My idea is about an app that will have GPS services and actions based on GPS locations, so I started following tutorials from the basics up, now i'm following a basic tutorial about a GPS app (in Kotlin) that just displays the current location with an on/off switch.

I'm still getting familiar with Android Studio and all the methods etc, but as of now I got to solve many of my problem since the documentation is plenty.

For the last 4-5 days i'm struggling to get it to work since i never got to get the location from it, I've followed the tutorial, I've copied code from repositories that followed the same tutorial, but in the console I keep getting:

```
    2022-07-13 15:06:25.275 4791-4815/com.example.gps_activity_test W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: com.example.gps_activity_test requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.

2022-07-13 15:06:25.275 4791-4815/com.example.gps_activity_test W/GoogleApiManager: The service for com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzaz is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
```

up until today the second error message was logging

> android.gms.internal.service.zap

instead of

> android.gms.internal.location.zzaz

I've been searching for service.zap, or googlePlayServiceUtil or GoogleApiManager, but nothing to help, and I only found [this github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/issues/683) for an errorcode similar to mine, but I haven't understood much anything about it.

I've reinstalled google play services in my emulator, and tested the app on my physical phone but no luck.

Also using custom logging messages or displaying a text update only goes so far in the code before this problem blocks it from proceeding

The app seems to work fine, it doesn't crash, but the UI values stay at 0.0 not updating with the location informations, since I guess the app doesn't receive.

All the videos i've watched only ask for COARSE_LOCATION and FINE_LOCATION while only adding implementing the **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'** copied from the documentation and also added and removed others following what I understood from the docs

As a beginner, the android doc is kinda a nightmare to understand plus it seem to constantly change and reading questions/answers or tutorials from just a year ago, many methods or arguments are different or deprecated.

Any insights on what to do?
I've been stuck for 4-5 days with no step forward...
Going on with the tutorial seems useless, since it is all based on locations, so even if I copy all the new features and functions, I'd still be stuck not knowing if they're working or not.
thanks for your time, sorry if I didn't provide enough context

Answer (score 0):

- Reinstalled Android Studio
- Reinstalled the emulated device (specifically choosing one that has already google play store installed) and opened the project again.

Now it works also on my physical phone.